# RF transistor amplifier circuit does not work

Tags: transistors, amplifier, rf, antenna, microwave

I have a microwave NPN transistor ([MMBR941LT1](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/motorola/MMBR941BLT1.pdf)) which I want to use as an amplifier for a 2.4Ghz signal (from my Wifi router) but it doesn’t work. The signal is captured by a dipole antenna with each side of the antenna being a quarter of the signal wavelength. For 2.4Ghz this is ~ 31mm.

One side of the dipole antenna is connected to transistor base (via a 10nF capacitor, c1) while the other side is connected to ground.

The transistor collector is connected to battery positive terminal via a 100K resistor while the emitter is connected via a 2.6K resistor to ground. So the voltage potential between collector and emitter is about 6.0 V.

According to MMBR941LT1 transistor datasheet, at 2.4Ghz, the signal should be amplified by about 7 times  but when I measure it with a microammeter connected in parallel with the 1SS86 detector diode (works for 2.4 Ghz), the signal is not amplified at all, and appears to be even lower than when connected directly to the dipole antenna.

With diode and ammeter connected directly to the middle of the dipole antenna, I measure a current of ~ 70 uA at 10cm away from router but with the transistor circuit, the current is only ~ 4 uA.

Can someone help connect the transistor in such a way so that signal would be amplified before it gets to the 1SS86 detector diode?

[image]

Comment: Your ammeter is shorting the diode - you would normally measure current  in series.

Comment: You also need to bias your BJT base and 100 kohms is massively too big in value fo the collector resistor.

Comment: @shining_sun70:  [Here's the usual way to use a diode to detect RF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hXZj.png)

Comment: That's the test circuit from the BAT63 datasheet.  Your 1SS86 may (or may not) be good at 2.4GHz.  Its datasheet doesn't say -it doesn't mention the usable frequency range except to say "UHF."  The BAT63 **is** good for 2.4GHz.

Comment: 1) include a link to the datasheet of that NPN 2) *the signal should be amplified by about 7 times* it depends **A LOT** on how you use the transistor if you will get that amplification. If you're not experienced with RF then you will **NOT** be able to achieve that. Did do proper impedance matching? My guess is you didn't and just build a common emitter circuit with will work at low frequencies but will have terrible performance at 2.5 GHz unless you significantly change your circuit. I suggest looking up some circuits for 2.5 GHz and notice how they're **very different** from yours.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have eddited the question and added a link to the transistor datasheet: http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/motorola/MMBR941BLT1.pdf

@ JRE I have tested the 1SS86 diode and it detects about 70uA of current from the wifi router.

Comment: I will add to the other criticisms, that R2 is much too large. The input impedance of the transistor amplifier is largely a multiple of the emitter resistor. In your circuit, that makes the input impedance many times the impedance of the antenna. Because of the mismatch, it would not be surprising you would end up with gain less than one.

Comment: In addition to every other comment, I want to see how this is laid out, too. (I am so hoping this is not on a solderless protoboard.) And where is the resonant tank? (That's how we used to do it back in the day, anyway.) I'm not sure a dual-gate mosfet exists for this frequency, but if it does I might be looking for one, as well.